Why would aliens want to invade Earth?
Aliens invading earth is arguably a trope as old as old as the idea of life beyond the stars but many of the justifications for said invasions tend to be rather flimsy.
Resources such as water or precious metals are vastly more abundant and cheaper to mine in the solar system or earth, and invading to use humans as slaves doesn’t when you consider any space faring civilization would likely already have advanced automation leaving slave labor as a liability.
So my question why might aliens want to invade Earth? Note that when I say “invade” I’m mainly referring to the idea of aliens of at least human level intelligence wanting to conquer/colonize the earth, complete with ground troops, and not just simply chuck a big rock at us to eliminate potential competition.
Edit: for some added clarification and to make things simpler the aliens in question a carbon based being able to at least tolerate earth, and at the bare minimum have FTL communication.

there are several other questions asking this, what about them does not answer your question?

There is no truly logical justification for an interstellar civilization conducting a ground invasion of Earth, it's only a trope. If they want our planet because getting rid of us is easier than terraforming someplace else, they'd just do something like seed our atmosphere with an engineered pathogen.

@MS yeah that’s pretty much the main reason why I made this question to see if there’s ANY reason aliens would want to try to conquer earth. That’s also why I’m assuming they don’t want to just kill humanity considering that a interstellar empire could easily sterilize the planet without ever stepping foot.

Do you have any constraints on the aliens because of your plot? Some fixed things? Are they aquatic? Do they breathe Oxygen or Nitrogen? Can they fly or have Telekinesis? Something like that would be helpful to answer more specifically.

The absolutely most important factor needed to decide an answer would be 'Do the aliens have faster-than-light travel'? And 'Do they have faster-than-light communications'? Spending hundreds of years to send an army to Earth just to conquer it, and not knowing if it was successful or not for hundreds of more years, adds an entirely different perspective on any answer.

We don't write plot sorry. VTC.

Why did Putin want to invade Ukraine? Why did Hitler invade half of Europe? It's often more a question of internal politics and/or the personality of the leader than the target itself.

Why questions are almost never a good fit for this forum. The question why almost always is a request for motive, seeking to understand rationale and choice. All of these things refer back to plot, character, and narrative necessity.  Jeremy's example of "mangoes" being the reason for invasion is a perfect example of this. Clearly this has become a popular question, but in all honesty, none of these 15+ people should have even touched this question. It should have been closed as story based shortly after it was posted. I'm not saying it's a bad question! If we accepted story based (cont)

(cont) based questions here, yours would actually be a role model in my opinion! But for now, this is a question that doesn't fit the Stack Exchange model and doesn't fit our forum.

If you asked "Is this a valid reason for my aliens to invade Earth," it might be okay... but not a brainstorming question, where even "they like mangoes" could be a good answer.

I would highly recommend you look up the channel Isaac Arthur. He has a fantastic series exploring the motives behind alien life's development. I think one argument he made is that its just easier to scare a civilization into surrendering than actually invading and fighting them. If you can travel to other stars, you can blow up a continent  as well and when you do, nobody is going to complain when you say you're in charge.

Space
There is one thing an alien species always needs more of. Space. Why? Because any alien civilisation making the effort to visit us is near certainly a species that is always expanding. There are a lot of reasons for such expansion, like doing it before other species do it before you, robbing you of that potential space. Short term it might not be a bad thing, but long term you do need to vacate the premise, because of reasons like stars expanding, or preventing a random cosmic event to kill off your whole species in a single shot.
If your species is expanding, you will always need more space. And why jump through hoops of terraforming, or megacities that need to be air tight? You have a planet in the goldilocks zone, reasonably protected against larger asteroids and the like, which will stay there for the foreseeable future.
Invade Earth because it is prime real estate for your expanding species.

Or, to use the immortal word popularized by famous alien leader who did try to conquer the world, Lebensraum.

The thing with space is there's oodles of it, and barring the most unlikely vagaries of random chance (over where they evolved) nearly all of it will be far closer to them than we are, and if they have the technological advances needed to reach us they will have the technological advances to utilise the oodles of space far closer to them with far less effort and investment in time and resources than it would take to reach us .. you need a reason other than space, and as resources (power etc) are subject to the same closer oodles situation as space you need a reason other than resources too.

@Pelinore That’s valid, but by that logic the only justification for them ever even interacting with us at all is because they happen to be right there (cosmologically speaking), and thus we’d be within their targeted areas of expansion.

@controlgroup Yep, it's pretty much the real answer to the Fermi paradox > "space is big, like really big, are you telling me you hadn't noticed?" .. but there is still curiosity, both scientific and 'just for the sheer hell of it', those shouldn't be entirely discounted as potential motives.

@Pelinore Of course - and we’re talking about science fiction anyway, where we can consider whatever semi-plausible circumstances that we want. This question is less about the astrodynamics and cosmology and more about the sociology.

Lebensraum
They want or need more living room. Their experts forecasted that conquering Earth will be cheaper and very much faster than terraforming a comparable planet.
The need or desire for more territory has motivated plenty of expansionist wars.

To be "benevolent" dictators
The aliens notice that Earth has lots of suffering and injustice. The aliens care about all intelligent life, and so they want to rule Earth with their more just government.
However, despite them caring about intelligent life, they might still have alien values compared to us. They may have a different definition of "benevolent". For example, maybe the aliens think chess is evil so they ban it.
Some of the aliens also might just be power hungry; the military leader dreams of having absolute authority over an intelligent civilization, and hopes the government back home will grant them rule of Earth if he can pretend to be benevolent. Or it could just be a small band of space pirates that likewise crave rule over an intelligent civilization.
Or the aliens could be truly benevolent and actually be the "good guys" of the story.

This is always a justification to sell the idea to the public, but not really the reason for doing it.

This would be entirely dependent on genre conventions.
For starters its obviously not resources or energy. The three reasons I would give is thus.
Ideological
The aliens are driven to bring all other sapient races under their control. Maybe if Earth isn't brought under their control, our souls will burn in hell unless we are able to get Space Jesus to forgive our sins.
Maybe they believe all other sapients are inherently evil and must be killed, but they also have a regard for our ecosystem.
Maybe they simply believe that they have the perfect method of governance and all else is intolerable.
Paranoia and Threat Prevention
They believe strongly in the Dark Forest Theory. Only instead of genocide their imperative is to invade and permanently occupy pre-space faring races.
Biological
Raw materials might be abundant throughout the universe. But only on Earth can you find human, beetles, terran trees, terran jellyfish, terran bacteria and viruses.
A bucket of Terran sea water or chunks of Amazon Rainforest soil might be worth more than gold to them.
Though random, the biosphere is a unique 4.5 billion year old archive of experiments in biochemistry, cognition, nano-machinery, material science, driven by self replicating microbots.
While I have no doubt they must have insane advances in their own fields. Maybe the sheer complexity of it all is something that simply can't be simulated or engineered.
The aliens for whatever reason see something that can be exploited or worth attaining their.
The Esoteric
Sci fi is no stranger to magic, woo, or implausible concepts.
Maybe it turns out the vitalists were correct, and life is driven by mana or life energy that can be extracted and used for their own ends.
Maybe their Gods are real and demands the sacrifice of sapients in exchange for boons.
Maybe the quantum brain microtubule people are correct and it turns out making an AI as competent as a sapient entity is effectively impossible.
Maybe they've decided it was better to harvest our brains to power their video game consoles or navigate hyperspace or whatever the aliens decide they need our intelligence for.

In The Forbin Project, the Martians came for oxygen.  In War of the Worlds, I think it was because humans were food for them.

Proof of work.
In the early days of cryptocurrency, the basis of value was in your ability to burn fossil fuels.  Pile up more coal than everyone else in the world, set it on fire, and use the heat to provide cryptographic certification of a ledger, and you have the right to say which user's ransom fees were fairly credited to the right account.
The discovery of unlimited free energy created a massive financial crisis.  How could anyone know whether their hard-earned drug money would stay in their cartel's account, if some nerd could tweak a dark matter coupling and pour out more energy than all the other power plants on Earth?
Today, proof of work is accomplished by a network of organoid intelligence modules, each using your own species' brain cells spun into an artificial network of consciousness copied from recorded individuals.  The complexity of the network is tested in more creative ways, which in vulgar but not inaccurate terms has been called "Eternal Torment".  For the network to hit its benchmarks, it needs to emulate the consciousnesses of innumerable sentient beings.  To stay ahead of the rat race, that number must continually increase.
The problem is that the Homeworld has run out of subjects.  The cities are depopulated, the countryside held by paranoid tyrants with pre-programmed homunculi dedicated to protect them, and the tyrants are very, very careful about paying their credit card bills.  This leaves outsourcing as the only logical alternative.
Seize the planet, scan all of the unique contacts, broadcast them to the network for reemulation, and move on.

Matrix on steroids!

It’s sort of nightmare fuel, which I love… An alien “overlord” (particularly rich crypto investor) comes to conquer Earth in its entirety and puts all humans into a hell-Matrix, not even for power generation or to keep us down like in the original movie, but just to earn money slightly faster than their competitors.

There is a late 80's/1990 film called "I Come In Peace" (Or Dark Angel, idk why). One of those fantastically bad action movies. The premise of the movie is that the alien, a drug dealer, comes to earth, terrorizes, predominantly women, so that they produce a rush of chemicals/hormones/endorphins and he extracts them, killing them in the process. He does this to sell on the intergalactic black market as an illegal drug.
From this great bad movie is the only example I have come across that made it plausible for any type of invasion of earth.
If the premise can be made that some chemical compounds can't be synthesized easily or economically, I think this holds up. Not just for drugs but nearly any biological chemical compound that can be found in nature.

Desperation
Let's be honest, an advanced spacefaring civilization probably doesn't need anything from Earth. As you say, it has all the physical resources it could ever ask for.
But what if you weren't dealing with a whole civilization? What if it just a small faction, like pilgrims searching for the promised land, a splinter group seeking new territory, or refugees fleeing from a war?
We can easily imagine a District-9 like situation, where aliens show up on Earth's doorstep unannounced with a small fleet of ships, limited resources, and nowhere else to go. We might be able to arrange a deal with them, but human (and alien) nature being what it is, it's much more likely we have to fight over who gets Earth's resources.
Incidentally, this also makes an invasion much more easily defeatable. One planet is never going to be able to defeat a space faring empire, but Earth might be able to scrape out a victory if the invaders can only draw on the limited resources, they brought with them. In a war of Earth vs. a cobbled together army made of refugees, Earth might just win.

Very simple. We have a planet with liquid water and we're within reach of their technology.
Either their planet is self destructing or they want/need to expand.
The key point is we're within reach. There may be a trillion liquid water planets, but if you can't reach them within whatever timeframe you need to, then they're useless to you.
It's the classic Martian invasion story and totally valid. Not a lot of different from many invasions we've had in our history.
But there doesn't need to be an overwhelming reason. Humans have launched invasions for no other reason than keeping their military employed. Some of the biggest were just for a leaders personal glory or blood thirst.

Sport
Predator got it right.
Say you're a race which values hunting prowess as a result of a deeply predatory past.  The ultimate game (but not the most dangerous game), therefore, is another sapient being.
But you are an advanced species.  Outside of deeply antisocial or deranged individuals, you don't kill each other anymore; you don't even have wars.
What to do?
And then, your equivalent of SETI discovers that there is alien intelligence in the universe!  And you have FTL drives!
The aliens think that your troopships are an invading army, but no... they're game wardens.

Or a 'team sport' - attack Earth with your team to gain points in some tournament. Points allocated depend on the level of technological development of the opponent (Earth). Of course, as a plot twist, the aliens would never fight to the finish of Earth as they would always want a rematch. When the clock runs out, they all go 'home'.

Boredom.
The aliens are easily bored and their only rule is "don't harm another of us". One of them stumbled over Earth and thought "hey, this will be a great playground for a while. So what if it gets wrecked, those puny humans don't count."
It told some of its fellow aliens about this planet that it found and it just snowballed from there.

A slight variant of the answer by AllSeeingEye33:
In the best tradition of pulp space opera, the aliens are biochemically mostly compatible with us. They can take a deep breath on a pollen-filled meadow and not collapse from allergic shock, they can eat a human-made sandwich and get most of their required nutrients, etc. Same for their plants and animals. The reverse is true as well, of course. When goats and sheep come across their prize petunia, the furry suction cleaners win.
Snobs on their worlds like to pretend that a sort-of-wine from sort-of-grapes grown in yet another ecosystem is the greatest thing since the invention of pizza. Realistically, nobody will taste the difference between a good hydroponic vintage and the "real genuine" food, but snobs would never admit that. They hire personal sommeliers as a form of status symbol and carry on for ages what they were told about this or that vintage.
So their agri-corporations need farms on many different planets. But is is cheaper to have locals stop the herbivores from devouring the sort-of-grapes first then to invent robots for the job. Would an alien AI realize that a fox actually keeps rabbits at bay and should be protected?
So they could hire humans to grow that stuff for them. And get neat new recipes like salted caramel popcorn in the bargain. How many billions of man-years of labor would we offer for a working stardrive?
But these aliens use the awesome power of their starships to conquer Earth instead. Why buy what they can steal?

Stargate

Your starships carries guns troops etc. why to bother with farming/mining tools when you already have "convincing" arsenal with you?
Yet you still have to work out that every cargo have non zero probability of carrying nukes or squad of superheros...
Because it's nice to rule be feared and abuse lesser species

Tourist Trap
Your highly developed society with free energy nearly free food etc. needs to spend credits somehow so:

You turn NY into hunting ground.
Mount Everest in five supernova resort.
Rent Australia for homegrown dictators.
Etc.

Technology/Knowledge
Yeah humans have puny tech but:

We couldn't communicate with them efficiently and some apocalyptic in scale conflict started between our species - but we would like to avoid it in future and study their language/s
They came to same results but using different ways which is interesting an may have some value for us (simplifying our tech)



Just like humans think brains of a poor monkey is a delicacy so will other life forms.  Animal abuse occurs nonstop in Earth.  We will be cattle to higher life form.  Twilight Zone "To Serve Man"

Blockquote


Aliens visited Earth and discovered mangoes.... in particular, they discovered that they absolutely love mangoes, and they want to export as many of them as possible to the homeworld, where they will fetch an outrageous price.  Unfortunately, the only place mangoes grow well is on Earth, which means Earth must now be converted (to the extent possible) into a giant mango plantation to support this new export market.  Any non-mango species on the planet, such as those funny-looking bald-ape-things, are just going to have to find somewhere else to live instead.  You can't stop progress!

Wait til they try pawpaws.

I don't know any reason why aliens would want to invade Earth.
But I can think of many reasons why aliens might want to conquer Earth.
You might think you have to invade a place to conquer it, but that is not true.  You might not able to imagine conquering a place without getting boots (or tentacle pads) on the ground, but lots of science fiction writers can imagine ways to do so.
Assume for the moment that there are methods of conquering, annexing, and ruling planets which don't involve invading those planets.  What could be possible reasons for conquering, annexing, and ruling worlds?
Possibly the aliens might want to conquer a primitive 21st century Earth  before Earth eventually becomes advanced enough to potentially conquer them, for example.
